# How to Check if object/row is still referenced by another object?

Tags: php, yii, reference, foreign-keys

As well all know if a database row is referenced by another, it cannot be deleted unless the one referencing gets deleted first.

I've been using Yii for some time now, and I have a question, here's my scenario:

Suppose you have loaded two types of objects:

```
$object1 = Model1::model()->findByPk($pk);
$object2 = Model2::model()->findByPk($pk);
```

Now each **$object1 has foreign keys referring to $object2**, and we all know $object2 cannot be deleted if $object1 has not yet been deleted given the fk relationship. Is there a way/ function in Yii that checks whether there are other objects that are still referenced to **$object2**?

like:

```
if(//$object2 has no longer any other objects referring to it){
$object2->delete();
//do something here
}
```

I know this can be done by making sure that $object1 is deleted first. But regardless of whether object1 is deleted or not, is there a function that does this checking? Any idea or piece of code would be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really a database problem. You basically need to do a query for every table foreign key that relates to the table you are trying to delete

But there is a number of solutions depending on your requirements

But the easiest way is to catch the database exception that gets thrown when trying to delete

E.g.

```
try
{
    $object2->delete();
}
catch(CDbException $ex)
{
    //unable to delete code here
}
```

This is very basic though as you don't know what tables cause the foreign key violation.

Otherwise you need to write code to check for every foreign key (this might be able to be accomplished using the database meta data that Yii has)

Comment: Thank you sir! ive actually thought of checking all the matched object1's foreign key if they still refer to object2,..glad this was easier!